# Plant ID: Is this a Dischidia?

Tags: identification

I bought this plant roughly two years ago. It has grown well in my garden. The seller told me is a Dischidia, but no name of species was provided. There are, however, few things I noticed which would say otherwise:

1. Dischidias should flower somewhat like Hoyas, though with fewer flowers. This plant has never flowered, though it should have flowered twice if the conditions were right. I give it the same growing condition I give my Hoyas.
2. The plant has tendrils, but I never saw a Dischidia with tendrils. These are not aerial roots, as they wrap around things, and don't look like roots.
3. The stem remains green and does not become barky. Maybe it's too early to say. In addition, one picture shows that the stems have "veins" which make them fibrous. The stem looks like a jasmin stem, but the leaves are quite different.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The tendrils look like the plant wants a wall to cling to.  Do dischidia do that?

Comment: By the way, come and knock on our door, we've been waiting for you.